# Using mypy with a recursive type

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Mypy doesn't support recursive types. Let's say we have such a type, and we want mypy to ignore it:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypedDict

class Foo(TypedDict):
    foo: Foo
```

When faced with this code, `mypy --show-error-codes` says:

```
test.py:5: error: Cannot resolve name "Foo" (possible cyclic definition)  [misc]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Now this is intentionally a cyclic definition, and I want to keep it that way. So my question is how can I ignore this error without also ignoring other type errors.

I could disable the entire `misc` error code via the config file, but that would also mean skipping other types of errors:

```
disable_error_code = "misc"
```

I could also use a type comment:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypedDict

class Foo(TypedDict):
    foo: Foo # type: ignore[misc]
```

But then I have to put this comment into every recursive struct (and I have several).

Is there a more general mechanism to ignore this particular "cycle" error in my whole project, given that it doesn't have a unique error code?

Comment: Support for this was recently added to master in https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/13297 that can be enabled with the `--enable-recursive-aliases` flag, which hasn't been released yet as of now.